# Dynamic X-axis graph that will change according to the count of rows

Tags: php, mysql, graph, date

Let's say I have a mysql table with an id, some measurements and a DATE column.

Example: id, measurements, date_entered

This table stores some measurements of a patient so as to keep a record for him.
I want to make a graph which according to the count of rows that exist in the database will change dynamically the X-axis.

For example, if there are only 7 rows in the table I need to represent 7 days to the graph with the measurement for every day. If there are more than 14 days, I want it to change to respresent 2 weeks on X-axis and the average measurements(average for 1 week and average for the other too) on Y-axis and so on from weeks to months.

Can anyone help me on this? I cannot think of something that will do in my case..
I use JPGraph to make the line graph but i don't have a problem there. My problem is on how to handle the results.

I hope you will understand what I need! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
// Get the results from the database
$query = "SELECT `data_col` FROM `table` WHERE `condition_col` = 'some value'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Get all results into array and count them
$results = array();
for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++) {
  $results[] = $row;
}

// Re-format the data depending on number of results
$data = array();
if ($i < 14) { // Less than 14 days, show per day
  foreach ($results as $row) {
    $data[] = $row['data_col'];
  }
} else if ($i < 56) { // Less than 8 weeks, show per-week
  $thisweek = array();
  for ($j = 0; isset($results[$j]); $j++) { // Loop the results
    $thisweek[] = $results[$j]['data_col']; // Add result to this week total
    if ($j % 7 == 0 && $j > 0) { // Every 7 days...
      $data[] = array_sum($thisweek) / 7; // ...calculate the week average...
      $thisweek = array(); // ...and reset the total
    }
  }
  // If there is an incomplete week, add it to the data
  $data[] = array_sum($thisweek) / count($thisweek);
} else { // 8 weeks or more, show per-month
  $thismonth = array();
  for ($j = 0; isset($results[$j]); $j++) { // Loop the results
    $thismonth[] = $results[$j]['data_col']; // Add result to this month total
    if ($j % 28 == 0 && $j > 0) { // Every 28 days...
      $data[] = array_sum($thismonth) / 28; // ...calculate the month average...
      $thismonth = array(); // ...and reset the total
    }
  }
  // If there is an incomplete month, add it to the data
  $data[] = array_sum($thismonth) / count($thismonth);
}

// $data now contains an array from which you should be able to draw your
// graph, where array keys are (sort of) x values and array values are y
// values.
```

Obviously, this solution assumes a 28-day month - it does not use the calendar, simply the number of days. You could do something horrible involving working out the stats based on some values returned by `date()` or similar, but this would likely drastically increase the calculation overhead and slow the process down.

Hopefully this will give you a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I will test it soon, but I think it will do!

Comment: Hmm, I get **Fatal error: Unsupported operand types on line 27**  It's this line: `$thisweek += $results[$j]['data_col'];` and that is because $thisweek is an array, how can I fix this?

Comment: @Andrew apologies for the delayed response, must have missed the notification - the two lines ins question should read `$var[] =` instead of `$var +=` - I have updated the code example above.

Comment: I did it this way. `array_push($thisweek, $results[$j]['data_col']);` And it worked. It is ok, right?

Comment: Yep, `array_push($array, $val)` does exactly the same as `$array[] = $val` - I prefer the second, but it's a pure point of personal preference, and there is nothing wrong with the way you have done it.